# What does this text bubble mean? i believe it's kanji

Tags: characters, handwriting

[image]
i cannot for the life of me figure out what this means... been trying to find out through the yomiwa mobile app, looking up online, and trying to match this to some kanji for over an hour
halp

Answer (score 5):

It's probably chinese 咪 which is an onomatopea for cat sounds [(source)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/cj/17521/meaning/m0u/).